# Difference with unit testing controller and service method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockmvc

I wanted to test same method from controller and service layer. The question is: Why do I have to use `@MockBean` annotation in controller, why not `@Mock` annotation for `BookFindOperationsService bookService`. Same question for service, why do I need to `@Mock` repository, why not to use `@MockBean`? Could you give me difference between these two?

Here is controller:

```
@RestController
public class BookFindOperationsController {

    private final BookFindOperationsService bookService;

    @Autowired
    public BookFindOperationsController(BookFindOperationsService bookService) {
        this.bookService = bookService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/books/author/{authorID}")
    public List<Book> findBooksByAuthor(@PathVariable String authorID) {
        return bookService.findBooksByAuthor(authorID);
    }

}
```

Here is service class:

```
@Service
public class BookFindOperationsService {
    private final BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BookFindOperationsService(BookRepository bookRepository) {
        this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
    }

    public List<Book> findBooksByAuthor(String authorID) {
        return bookRepository.findByAuthorAllIgnoreCase(authorID);
    }
}
```

Service test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BookFindOperationsServiceTest {

    @Mock
    BookRepository bookRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    BookFindOperationsService bookFindOperationsService;

    @Test
    public void findBooksByAuthor() {
        Book book = createDummyBook();
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(book);

        when(bookRepository.findByAuthorAllIgnoreCase("Henryk Sienkiewicz")).thenReturn(books);

        assertEquals(1, bookFindOperationsService.findBooksByAuthor("Henryk Sienkiewicz").size());
    }

private Book createDummyBook() {
        return new Book("W pustyni i w puszczy", "Henryk Sienkiewicz", "dramat", true);
    }
```

Controller test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BookFindOperationsController.class)
public class BookFindOperationsControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    BookFindOperationsService bookService;

    @Test
    public void findBooksByAuthor() throws Exception {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        Book book = new Book("W pustyni i w puszczy", "Henryk Sienkiewicz", "dramat", true);
        books.add(book);

        when(bookService.findBooksByAuthor("Henryk Sienkiewicz")).thenReturn(books);

        String expected = "[{\"id\":0,\"title\":\"W pustyni i w puszczy\",\"author\":\"Henryk Sienkiewicz\",\"category\":\"dramat\",\"available\":true}]";

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/books/author/Henryk Sienkiewicz")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andReturn();

        String content = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();

        assertEquals(expected, content);

        verify(bookService, times(1)).findBooksByAuthor(anyString());
    }
```

Comment: @vmaldosan nah, I want to know why I can not use Mock instead of MockBean. Im getting NullPointer or something.

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between [`@Mock`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.4/org/mockito/Mock.html) and [`@MockBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) is that the former belongs to Mockito framework where as the later belongs to Spring Test Framework under Mockito.

The `@MockBean` creates/replaces a Spring Bean with a Mocked bean so that other Spring Loaded beans (Controller etc.) can make use of it. That is why you need it when you use `MockMvc.perform`.

The `@Mock` annotation doesn't work with Spring Context. It will just try to map a mocked object marked with this annotation to a property of an objected marked with `@InjectMocks`.

**UPDATE**

When `@WebMvcTest(BookFindOperationsController.class)` is used a Spring Context is created which has all the necessary beans to support the running of `BookFindOperationsController` class as a Web Application. Which means any Interceptors, Filters, Converters also need to be loaded in the Spring Context. This Spring Context will also load a `BookFindOperationsService` of its own which is not a mock but an actual implementation. But for Testing you need to a Mock that is why you annotate that bean with `@MockBean` to instruct the Spring Context to use the Mocked one instead of the Actual. This is an integration test because you test whether all components work together correctly.

When you use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` There won't be any Spring Context created implicitly. So you can not use `@MockBean` because there is no Spring Beans to be mocked. This is a unit test because you are only testing `BookFindOperationsService` while mocking `BookRepository` without actually saving anything on Database.

Hope this explains well.

Comment: Yeah, but... Service is also a bean. Why in service test I can not make `@MockBean  BookFindOperationsService bookFindOperationsService` ?

Comment: Please read the update.

Comment: It seems that I do not understand why first is integration test and the other is unit test. Why I can not write @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) also in `BookFindOperationsController` and conversely why I can not write @WebMvcTest(BookFindOperationsService .class) ? For me, test in controller is also unit test, because I do not save anything on DataBase.

Comment: Read the first paragraph in update section slowly.

Comment: to be honest, I've read it about 5+ times :D Still cant get it. In my opinion, you've written about what is happening when I use @Webmvc... or `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` annotation, no why I should use it and which I should use it  particular class. For me, these two tests are the same. I test the same method, but from different Components. Really, want to know what exactly is going on here.

Comment: Is there any chance to get answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53776659/difference-with-unit-testing-controller-and-service-method/53777238?noredirect=1#comment94408722_53777238 ?

Answer (score 0):

@MockBean is used to add mock objects to the Spring application context. The mock will replace any existing bean of the same type in the application context. You can use it in integration tests

@Mock is used in unit test to replace some implementation.
Look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean)

One important note when using @MockBean. In this cases spring context is not cached and if you have many integration tests initializations of context could take a lot of time.

Comment: Ye, but those two tests are unit test and here I have `@MockBean`. Why I can not use @Mock instead of @MockBean?

Comment: And second test work for you without any additional annotations before class? It look like integration test not unit.

Comment: seems like didnt paste annotation. Edited question. Check it out.

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) means that you start spring context to run this test and @mockBean replace existing bean

Comment: yeah, I know what these annotation do, but it was not a question. I asked why I can not use @Mock instead of @MockBean? Both are unit test. Why for you, controller test is integration test?

Comment: For me it's integration test because you start spring context. So you start context and you want to replace dependency which is some bean - you use MockBean. If you use in your test bookFindOperationsController.findBooksByAuthor in this case you can use Mock because spring context is not needed here.

Comment: You are saying that in `BookFindOperationsControllerTest ` I can write Mock instead of MockBean?